# How to run same application multiple times in a pc with different credential at same time

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, credentials, simulator

Suppose , i have a apps called "GEM",

to make it run in Operation system in personal computer i need userid and password to log in.Now whenever i login to "GEM" with a user id named 'tom' and password "12345", it works fine but when i need to login with another id like 'jerry' with password "98765" then previous id of "Tom" get change and replace by "Jerry", which is normal in a application process.

But i want to make "GEM" running at same time with both "Tom" and "Jerry" id simultaniusly.none of them will get shut down in process.How can i achieve it without using vmware or virtual box.

i tried using vmware and virtual box for opening "GEM" with multiple credential but i have not much hardware capacity to hold more than 2 or 3 apps in running. I want to make like 150/200 apps running with different user id and password at same time for process. For achievinng better result i need to keep it running all time. which is not possible to achieve for me. Suggest me with guideline with my Pc Configuration stated below :

Device name Server
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400 CPU @ 2.90GHz   2.90 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.85 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As mentioned above. Please mention what kind of an App is this. Just a heads up, if you're talking about a full-fledged desktop app with a GUI, you may need to run that in VMs. However, if you're running a CLI app or a web app hosted on a local server i.e. localhost, you can get away with docker containers.